# Issue with callbacks using Expressjs + JWT + Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, jwt

I have a project using authentication based on **JWT** with **Expressjs** and **Angularjs**, but I need to use [node-dbox](https://github.com/sintaxi/dbox) in order to access the Dropbox files of my users.

The problem comes when I try to save the token of my users that comes from Dropbox, this is an example of a callback authorization

https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=#{ request_token.oauth_token }

Is there a way, my API built with the **JsonWebToken** module, can know whose user is the token that comes from dropbox save it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `request_token` to get the `access_token` (using the Dropbox API) then use the `access_token` to get user id (using the Dropbox API).

Here is the documentation :

- Oauth : https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauthguide
- API : https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

Comment: But in my API built with Dropbox how can I attach the token I receive to the current user logged in.